# How can I fix this problem? list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas, list

tried to get a Percentage of Adj. high and Adj. Close, from WIKI/GOOGL data.
but got error

```
df=quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
df=[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume',]]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close'])/ df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
```

----> 1 df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close'])/ df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: df is a list. Lists are accessed by something like df[1] or df[2:4]

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: did you mean df=df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume',]]?